# How to calculate the cardinality of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-17}]/(3, 1+\sqrt{-17})$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-17}]/(\sqrt{-17})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

thanks for taking the time to look at my problems.

I was trying to calculate the norm of $(3, 1 + \sqrt{-17})$ and $(\sqrt{-17})$.
The second one is 17 because of the norm of the element $\sqrt{-17}$, but how does this follow from $|\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-17}]/(\sqrt{-17})|$?

I tried to calculate $|\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-17}]/(3, 1+\sqrt{-17})|$ and concluded that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-17}]/(3, 1+\sqrt{-17}) \cong \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ such that $|\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-17}]/(3, 1+\sqrt{-17})| = 3$. Is this correct?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have had three answers. There are two ways to thank people for their help here and for taking the time to look at your questions. You can upvote any answer you found helpful. And if you found one answer particularly helpful, you can "accept" it by clicking in the check mark next to it. If you didn't find any answer helpful, you can leave a comment asking for clarification, or you can edit your question to indicate what you still need addressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your computations are correct.

Since $-17\equiv3\bmod{4}$ our ring of integers is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-17}]$, so we may factor the ideal $(3)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-17}]$ by factoring

$$x^2 + 17 \equiv x^2 - 1 \equiv (x+1)(x+2) \bmod{3}.$$

This yields the ideal $(3,1+\sqrt{-17})$, and since 3 splits the norm of this ideal is 3.

To see this more directly, we can use the ring isomorphism theorems.  We have $(x^2+17) \subseteq (3,1+x) \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[x]$ from above, hence

$$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-17}]/(3,1+\sqrt{-17}) \cong
   \mathbb{Z}[x]/(3,1+x) \cong
   \mathbb{Z}/3$$

As for $(\sqrt{-17})$, the same argument works.

Answer (score 0):

Given $a+b\sqrt{-17}$, you can subtract $b(1+\sqrt{-17})$ to get a rational integer, then subtract an appropriate multiple of 3 to get 0, 1, or 2. So the quotient ring has at most 3 elements, indeed, has number of elements a divisor of 3, so it now suffices to show it's not 1.

If it's 1, then 1 is in the ideal, $1=3(a+b\sqrt{-17})+(1+\sqrt{-17})(c+d\sqrt{-17})$. Multiply everything out, and equate rational terms and equate irrational terms, to get the equations, $1=3a+c-17d$, $0=3b+c+d$. Subtraction yields $1=3(a-b-6d)$, a clear impossibility, so it's 3.

Answer (score 0):

You already seem know that the norm of a prinicipal ideal is the norm of its generator. Hence $|\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-17}]/(3)|=9$.

We have $(3) \subsetneq (3,1+\sqrt{-17}) \subsetneq (1)$, hence $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-17}]/(3,1+\sqrt{-17})$ is a non-trivial quotient of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-17}]/(3)$. A non-trivial quotient of a group with $9$ elements must have $3$ elements, hence we obtain

$$|\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-17}]/(3,1+\sqrt{-17})|=3$$

without having calculated the quotient (Which would be of course an easy task, too, as shown in the other answers).

Comment: It does take a bit of work to show that $(3,1+\sqrt{-17})\ne(1)$.